# Make Custom Object tab available to public website

Tags: apex, visualforce, website-integration

I created a public website which contains a visualforce page. I want to add a custom object's tab in this website but don't find any way out to do it. Any guidelines?

Comment: set permissions of site guest user

Comment: @Novarg where is this Guest user? I can't see it in the `users` of my dev org.

Comment: search setup for "Site guest", you'll find him